# Error with 'auditIfNotExists' while scaling up and scaling down Azure SQL DB using Rest API from Azure Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have been using Rest API from Azure Data factory to scale up and scale down Azure SQL DB.
This was running fine last couple of months. But recently I started getting some intermittent error. Sometimes the rest api from ADF showed below error.

"internalServerError","message: an unexpected error occurred while processing the request"

But when I check the database I found that the database is successfully scaled up / scaled down.

Even though, Azure SQL DB activity log shows an an error related to  'auditIfNotExists' Policy action.

Can anyone help me with this ?

I am using api-version 2017-10-01 ? Is this policy error related api version ? How to decide which api version we need to use ? Is it always latest version to use ?

Or is the error related to something else ?

Comment: Hi @SKDUTTA,, is the error solved fixed now?

Comment: Hi Leon , Yes , the error is fixed now. But do not know the reason why it was showing the internal error.